# cloudsql and datastore combined together with django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to find information on setting up my django+cloudsql application to be able to simultaneously use the datastore as well. Besides being an important topic to know about, I need it for image manipulation, which on appengine only seems to happen with the images API which is low level and uses the datastore.

Comment: Do you want to access both via the Django ORM?  Use django with cloudSQL, while accessing the datastore with the GAE native db or ndb interface is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got the impression that the Images API can only use the datastore. [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass) seems to clearly show that you can pass the `Image` class *either* a blob key, or a Google Storage filename, or the image data itself as a bytestring.

Comment: Thanks, I have found the same info in the meantime, but I am still curious about using both data storages simultaneously